# $\sqrt{n}$ with at least five equal among the first six digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$ which are not perfect squares and such that the decimal representation of $\sqrt{n}$ has the following property: among the first six digits there are at least five equal.

For example $\sqrt{2020} = 44.944410108488\ldots$ has five $4$s and one $9$ among its first six digits.

Comment: There are infinitely many.  Take, say, $\lfloor99999.01^2\rfloor$ and so on.

Comment: $2020$ times $100^n,$ $n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: What is the context for this problem?  It's easy to come up with infinite families of solutions.  Hard to imagine there's a pleasant classification.

Comment: I was just looking for special properties of 2020 and came up with this observation on my own.

Comment: If you take a number like $100^n-1$ for large $n$, its square root will begin with a very long string of $9's$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to $n\le 10^6$, there are $538$ non-squares whose square root has $5$ out of $6$ (decimal) digits equal:

[image]

There is a "staircase" pattern.

Here are all of the $538$ terms from above plot:

```
2020, 6543, 7903, 8080, 9779, 9980, 9982, 9984, 9986, 9988, 9990, 9992, 9994, 9996, 9998, 9999, 12346, 12347, 12348, 12359, 12368, 12569, 13715, 14668, 25957, 29279, 31605, 35679, 40894, 44568, 48498, 49294, 49374, 49382, 49383, 49384, 49385, 49386, 49396, 49405, 49414, 49561, 49650, 50725, 51630, 52543, 59753, 63616, 71111, 74105, 85394, 92011, 98178, 109120, 109782, 110911, 110978, 111091, 111098, 111109, 111110, 111111, 111112, 111113, 111114, 111115, 111118, 111131, 111138, 111151, 111178, 111311, 111378, 111445, 111779, 113120, 113794, 115147, 117878, 118642, 126420, 132011, 134444, 139378, 142716, 151234, 154711, 163575, 169013, 171764, 178272, 180153, 187778, 188742, 193991, 194873, 195757, 196643, 197264, 197353, 197442, 197495, 197504, 197513, 197522, 197527, 197528, 197529, 197530, 197531, 197532, 197533, 197534, 197535, 197540, 197549, 197558, 197575, 197620, 197709, 197798, 197887, 197976, 198421, 199313, 200207, 202000, 206520, 207531, 215709, 217778, 225098, 228271, 234686, 239012, 244475, 250001, 255586, 261235, 265797, 272716, 276209, 284445, 286820, 296420, 297631, 303111, 304213, 304214, 305318, 306424, 307532, 308087, 308198, 308309, 308420, 308531, 308586, 308597, 308598, 308609, 308620, 308631, 308636, 308637, 308638, 308639, 308640, 308641, 308642, 308643, 308644, 308645, 308646, 308653, 308664, 308675, 308686, 308753, 308864, 308975, 309086, 309087, 309754, 310868, 311984, 313102, 319853, 321111, 331264, 333827, 342875, 346790, 354686, 359999, 360001, 368044, 373457, 380277, 380278, 387161, 392711, 401111, 405344, 415309, 418177, 418178, 429753, 431211, 436480, 437802, 437803, 439127, 440453, 441781, 441782, 443112, 443644, 443645, 443778, 443911, 444044, 444177, 444178, 444311, 444364, 444377, 444378, 444391, 444404, 444417, 444418, 444431, 444436, 444437, 444438, 444439, 444440, 444441, 444442, 444443, 444444, 444445, 444446, 444447, 444448, 444457, 444458, 444471, 444484, 444577, 444578, 444711, 444844, 445778, 445779, 447115, 448453, 457877, 457878, 459382, 459383, 471511, 474567, 474568, 485344, 489999, 490001, 500949, 505679, 505680, 515204, 515205, 521605, 521606, 529660, 537778, 544315, 544316, 554197, 554198, 559171, 570864, 574226, 574227, 587777, 587778, 589482, 589483, 594098, 595640, 595641, 597185, 598731, 598732, 600280, 601830, 601831, 603383, 603384, 603849, 603850, 604005, 604160, 604161, 604316, 604471, 604472, 604626, 604627, 604782, 604783, 604829, 604844, 604845, 604860, 604875, 604876, 604891, 604906, 604907, 604922, 604923, 604927, 604928, 604929, 604930, 604931, 604932, 604933, 604934, 604935, 604936, 604937, 604938, 604939, 604940, 604941, 604953, 604954, 604969, 605093, 605094, 605249, 606494, 606495, 608053, 620593, 620594, 622345, 636449, 639999, 640001, 654300, 654301, 657902, 670578, 670579, 676050, 687056, 694444, 694445, 703734, 713086, 713087, 720611, 720612, 731975, 731976, 737689, 737690, 751110, 751111, 754967, 754968, 770493, 770494, 772445, 775964, 775965, 777727, 777728, 779492, 781258, 781259, 783027, 783028, 784798, 784799, 786571, 786572, 788346, 788701, 788702, 788878, 788879, 789056, 789057, 789234, 789235, 789411, 789412, 789589, 789590, 789767, 789768, 789945, 789980, 789981, 789998, 789999, 790016, 790033, 790034, 790051, 790052, 790069, 790070, 790087, 790088, 790105, 790108, 790109, 790110, 790111, 790112, 790113, 790114, 790115, 790116, 790117, 790118, 790119, 790120, 790121, 790122, 790123, 790124, 790125, 790140, 790141, 790300, 790301, 791901, 791902, 808000, 808001, 809999, 810001, 828099, 830124, 830125, 846399, 850494, 850495, 864899, 871111, 871112, 883599, 891975, 891976, 902499, 913086, 913087, 921599, 934444, 934445, 940899, 956048, 956049, 960399, 977900, 977901, 980099, 982080, 984063, 986048, 988035, 990024, 992015, 994008, 996003, 998000, 998199, 998200, 998399, 998400, 998599, 998600, 998799, 998800, 998999, 999000, 999199, 999200, 999399, 999400, 999599, 999600, 999799, 999800, 999819, 999820, 999839, 999840, 999859, 999860, 999879, 999880, 999899, 999900, 999919, 999920, 999939, 999940, 999959, 999960, 999979, 999980, 999981, 999982, 999983, 999984, 999985, 999986, 999987, 999988, 999989, 999990, 999991, 999992, 999993, 999994, 999995, 999996, 999997, 999998, 999999
```

I'm not sure about a closed form for *all of them*.

There are *trivial* patterns such as  [Oscar Lanzi](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3486526/318073) answered, but there are also *nontrivial* terms.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers consisting of all $1$ digits in base $10$ and even number of these digits will have square roots beginning with as many $3$'s, thus $\sqrt{11}=3.the..., \sqrt{1111}=33.33..., \sqrt{111111}=333.333...$.